# Hibernate Delete Query is not working

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This Query is not working.It showing  my sql grammer exception error.

`mappingHeaderId` is the object table `FinanceAccountMappingHeader` ,

`busineeUnitId` is the  object of `TableBranchesCompany` ,

`customerId` is the object of table `TableClient`

`customerSiteId` is the object of `TableRigs and

`customerSiteAdressId` is the object of table `CustomerSiteAddress`

Please write the correct query

```
      Query q1 = session.createQuery("DELETE FROM FinanceAccountMappingDetails WHERE "+
                "status=:status AND mappingHeaderId.businessUnitId.id =:buisnessUnit "
                +"AND mappingHeaderId.customerId.id =:customerId AND mappingHeaderId.customerSiteId.id=:customerSiteId "+                 
                 "AND ownershipId.id=:ownershipId AND mappingHeaderId.customerSiteAdressId.id=:customerSiteAddresssId");
        q1.setParameter("status", "active");
        q1.setParameter("buisnessUnit", buisnessUnit);
        q1.setParameter("customerId",customerId);
        q1.setParameter("customerSiteId",customerSiteId);
        q1.setParameter("ownershipId",ownershipId);
        q1.setParameter("customerSiteAddresssId",customerSiteAddresssId);
        q1.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message ?

Comment: Please show your Entity. You called everything *_Id*, but using an object syntax in the HQL Query: `mappingHeaderId.businessUnitId.id`

Answer (score 1):

One delete queries can't delete multiple table record, at a time delete one or more record but same table. So please remove other table ID column from your delete query.